# switch layout columns based on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, inheritance, erb

so basically my application looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="content_left">
        // Some Stuff
    </div>

    <div id="content_right">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

now i want to switch between a two column layout and a single column layout based on the controller (at best: also based on the method i'm using).

between the body and the content and also in there head there is way too much stuff for simply creating a second layout and adding this as a `layout`call in my controller without too much code duplication.

what i would love to do is something like this:

all should use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
 // much stuff
 <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

and now i can switch between two layouts, f.e

single_col

```
<div id="content">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

or two_column

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content_left">
        // Some Stuff
    </div>

    <div id="content_right">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in the last yield there should be the view that is related to my controller and method.

is there an easy way to achieve this?

thanks for all hints.

PLEASE leave a comment if something is unclear.

Comment: have you found the right way for you to do this finally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the different parts of the layouts in partials! Then you render the partials based on what is in 
`params[:controller]` and `params[:action]`. For example:

```
<% if params[:controller] == "controller_name" %>
     <%= render 'partial_name1' %>
<% else %>
     <%= render 'partial_name2' %>
<% end %>
```

The `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` are always available! This is an example to show you how it works. Of cause there shjouldnt be any logic in the view aswell!

Answer (score 2):

You could use two layouts that would both render header and footer partials containing what's common to both.

OR, you use a <%= yield :sidebar %> and then inject something

```
<% content_for(:sidebar) do %>
  some stuff here
<% end %>
```

[Take a look at Rails guide section about those here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield)

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for a way to use a shared layout with two sub layouts inside, here you go:

add this to your application_helper.rb

```
  # Allows easy using nested layouts
  def inside_layout(layout = 'application', &block)
    render :inline => capture_haml(&block), :layout => "layouts/#{layout}"
  end
```

layouts/application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    -# your header content
  %body
    .content
      = yield
```

layouts/single_column.html.haml

```
= inside_layout do
  .middle
    = yield
```

layouts/two_column.html.haml

```
= inside_layout do
  .left
    -# your shared left content
  .right
    = yield
```

the column layouts can now be used like normal layouts, so you can just set them in your controller

```
layout "single_column"
```

Note: All markup is in [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) a gem which I can highly suggest.

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple layouts in a rails project. You could have a 2 column and a single column one.

To specify the layout used, provide it in the method in the controller.

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user
      format.html {render 'pages/index', :layout => 'home'}# index.html.erb
    else
      format.html {render 'pages/landingpage', :layout => 'landingpage'}# index.html.erb
    end
  end
end
```

For example the controller above, will render the the views `index.html.erb` and `landingpage.html.erb` based on the value of `current_user`. You can also only provide the layout parameter to `render` like `render :layout => 'home'`

You could also have a look at [nested layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) but I have never worked with those.

Comment: yes sure. but i don't want to use just two layouts, because there would be too much duplicate code. its more a 3-level-layout i need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sub_layouts

```
Class IndexController < ApplicationController

  def index

    def sub_layout
      "left"
    end

   end

 end
```

Add sub layouts to /app/view/shared/layouts/sub/_mysublayout.haml or .erb

in /app/views/layouts/application.haml/.erb * your main layout file*

= render :partial=>"layouts/sub/#{controller.sub_layout}"

With some checking for nils with rescue nil you can make this sub template load the layout for say a right or a left col, use this with great benefit in my apps. Its a big time saver and gives you the extra flexibility to set the layout on an action base.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that in your single column layout you have no information for your `content_left`. 
And in two column layout you have information for both `content_left` and `content_right`. 
There are lots of ways but im recommending something **completely controlled by CSS**.

CSS classes will be like following

```
#content_left{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
#content_right{
        background-color: green;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Now notice... if `content_left` div is empty then the `content_right` div will expand to full width. And you are ready with single column layout. And if you have data in `content_left` it will be showing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using helper method to set Dynamically sidebar,you can use as per your requirement.

```
<div id="main_content" class="<%= main_content_css_class %>">
   <%= yield %>
</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="<%= sidebar_css_class %>">
  <%= yield :sidebar %>
</div>
```

In Helper

```
def sidebar_enabled?
 current_page = "#{controller.controller_name}.#{controller.action_name}"
 current_controller = controller.controller_name
 pages = %w(home)
 return pages.include?(current_page) || pages.include?(current_controller)

end

def main_content_css_class
  sidebar_enabled? ? "grid_12" : "grid_16"
end

# Returns the CSS class for the 'sidebar' div depending on sidebar requirement
def sidebar_css_class
   sidebar_enabled? ? "grid_4" : "dont-show"
end
```

Using your code is also cleaner and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put classes on the body element for the controller and action name, as it comes in handy in many ways. Here's an example based on that strategy:

```
...
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
        // Some Stuff
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
...
```

then it's a matter of getting the right CSS. If you had a 'posts' controller, the sidebar is usually visible, and you want to hide it:

```
body.posts { #sidebar { display: none; } };
```

If you want it to only show up sometimes, you could invert the logic so it's usually hidden, then override with a more specific scope to show it. Or, you could have one column on all 'index' actions, two columns for everything else, etc.

The downside to this, and it's not insignificant, is that your views are coupled to the name of the controller. I.e. this strategy violates the "tell, don't ask" principle. I still think it's worth it, since I haven't been bit by a nasty refactoring involving this code yet. Usually it's a simple matter of changing a couple instances of the controller name in ex. "posts.css.scss" when renaming the file; no big deal. Just something to weigh.

Also, note that I picked more descriptive class names. "Left" and "right" are ephemeral, as your example demonstrates. "Sidebar" and "main" might not be what you have, but I'd make an attempt to describe what goes in them if possible.